# Получить список классов

Tags: c++, qt, рефлексия

Задача состоит в том, чтобы написать простой редактор объектов, с возможностью создавать, удалять объекты и редактировать свойства объектов разных классов. При этом запрещено использовать для этих целей операторы `switch`/`case`, добавление нового класса в систему не должно требовать изменение существующего кода.

Немного начал разбираться в метапрограммировании и рефлексии на Qt, понял, как можно для конкретного класса получить список методов и свойств (`QMetaObject`). Однако сейчас проблема состоит в том, как получить список, собственно, классов. Все классы имеют одного общего предка. 
На .NET это решается довольно просто, а вот найти решение для Qt мне не удалось. Может кто подскажет, реально ли вообще это сделать?

Comment: Всех классов или тех, что имеют в предках QObject?

Comment: QMetaObject::superClass оно?

Comment: @gil9red Тех, кто имеют в предках некий мой пользовательский базовый класс, который, в свою очередь, уже унаследован от QObject

Comment: @AlexanderChernin К сожалению, этот метод не статический, да и таким способом можно получить только родительский класс, зная дочерний, хотелось бы наоборот.

Comment: Список классов, для которых qt собрал мета информацию, средствами Qt получить нельзя. Передется регистрировать интересующие вас классы вручную.